# Show progress of HTTP Request in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am using the below code, to get data from API and add data to table. I want to show the users the progress of the API Request Made. Hence using If to get the status of the request using `readyState Property (IXMLHTTPRequest)`

Problem -

When this function is called, I just get one msgbox with 4.
What am I missing??

```
Option Compare Database

Dim ApiUrl As String
Dim reader As New XMLHTTP60
Dim coll As Collection
Dim Json As New clsJSONParser

Public Sub ApiInitalisation()
    ApiUrl = "http://private-anon-73376961e-countingappapi.apiary-mock.com/"
End Sub

Public Sub GetPerson()
On Error GoTo cmdLogIn_Click_Err

    'For API
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim contact As Variant

    Api.ApiInitalisation
    ApiUrl = ApiUrl & "users/5428a72c86abcdee98b7e359"

    reader.Open "GET", ApiUrl, False
    'reader.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    reader.send

    'Temporay variable to store the response
    Dim egTran As String
```

**Relevant Code Start**

```
    If reader.ReadyState = 0 Then
    MsgBox (0)
    End If

    If reader.ReadyState = 1 Then
    MsgBox (1)
    End If

    If reader.ReadyState = 2 Then
    MsgBox (2)
    End If

    If reader.ReadyState = 3 Then
    MsgBox (3)
    End If

    If reader.ReadyState = 4 Then
    MsgBox (4)
    End If


    '-------------
    ' Why is this code required?
    ' Not yet found answer

    'Do Until reader.ReadyState = 4
    '   DoEvents
    'Loop
    '-------------------
```

**Relevant Code End**

```
    ' Add data to Table
    If reader.Status = 200 Then
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblPerson", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

        egTran = "[" & reader.responseText & "]"
        Set coll = Json.parse(egTran)

        For Each contact In coll
            rs.AddNew
            rs!FName = contact.Item("name")
            rs!Mobile = contact.Item("phoneNumber")
            rs!UserID = contact.Item("deviceId")
            rs!SID = contact.Item("_id")
            rs.Update
        Next

    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to import data."
    End If

End Sub
```

*As per [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

0 (UNINITIALIZED) =

The object has been created, but not initialized (the open method has not been called).

(1) LOADING =

The object has been created, but the send method has not been called.

(2) LOADED =

The send method has been called, but the status and headers are not yet available.

(3) INTERACTIVE =

Some data has been received. Calling the responseBody and responseText properties at this state to obtain partial results will return an error, because status and response headers are not fully available.

(4) COMPLETED =

All the data has been received, and the complete data is available in the responseBody and responseText properties.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're missing some code or I'm misunderstanding, you're already using reader.send *prior* to checking the ReadyState.  It's always going to come back as Completed, unless it encounters a fatal error (and even then it may come back as Completed).

Comment: Considering your answer, I tried shifting all the `if` to before `reader.send`. But now I am getting 0

Comment: Which should tell you that it goes from uninitialized to completed instantaneously.  I don't think you can actually do whatever it is you're trying to accomplish, or at least not in the manner you're attempting.

Comment: I looked up some more information, from googling the IXMLHTTP. I found new property `onStatusChange`. Any Idea as to how we can implement this