# Download Json Obeject from URL by VBA

Tags: json, vba, ms-access, url

I have a MS Access project that requires me retrieve and parse a Json object from a URL. I have done parse part, but I cannot figure out the correct way to retrieve the Json from the URL. If I copy and paste the URL on IE, it will automatically download the Json object as .json file for me. I have searched solution by Google, and none of them works for me. I think the problem is that the URL looks like "https://******.com/rest/external/session/123", which is not similar to a standard XML HTTP request URL. So most solutions which use XMLHTTP request does not work for me.

I have tried to use following code to get it from URL. But all I get is homepage DOM tree instead of Json.

```
Dim wb As XMLHTTP
 Set wb = New XMLHTTP
 wb.Open "POST", "https://******.com/rest/external/session/123", False
 wb.send
 Do Until wb.Status = 200 And wb.ReadyState = 4
   DoEvents
 Loop
 Debug.Print wb.responseText
```

Anyone has any idea about what I should do here?
Any help is appreciated!

Updated:

1. I have tried both POST and GET http request. And it gave me the same result
2. Following are the processes captured by fiddler.

[This is captured processes if I copy the url directly on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBjzi.png)

[This is captured processes if I use the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMbPB.png)

Comment: Have you tried "GET"?

Comment: Would also suggest GET, and debugging the request with an HTTP monitoring tool such as Fiddler.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595437) It had code in the Question section which will help you achieving your desired objective

Comment: @Jules and Tim Williams , Yes, I have also tried GET. It gave me the same result.

Comment: @TimWilliams Please see my updates for the question.

Comment: From XMLHTTP you got status 302 - Redirection request.  What is the body of the 3rd request from your "use the code above"?

Comment: @Jules I will get DOM tree of the login page of the website. I am wondering whether it is because the request did not use my authorization session, although I tried to login the website before I run vba.

Comment: You have to login from xmlhttp. use Fidler to examine the login submit and replicate the url (if GET) or header (if POSt) from your xmlhttp.

Answer (score 0):

Just explaining the code logic below. You will need to work on it to build your own code.

```
Option Compare Database

Dim ApiUrl As String
Dim reader As New XMLHTTP60
Dim coll As Collection
Dim Json As New clsJSONParser

Public Sub ApiInitalisation()
    ApiUrl = "http://private-anon-73376961e-count.apiary-mock.com/"
End Sub

Public Sub GetPerson()
On Error GoTo cmdLogIn_Click_Err

'For API
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim contact As Variant

Api.ApiInitalisation
ApiUrl = ApiUrl & "users/5428a72c86abcdee98b7e359"

reader.Open "GET", ApiUrl, False
'reader.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
reader.send

'Temporay variable to store the response
Dim egTran As String

' Add data to Table
If reader.Status = 200 Then
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblPerson", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

    egTran = "[" & reader.responseText & "]"
    Set coll = Json.parse(egTran)

    For Each contact In coll
        rs.AddNew
        rs!FName = contact.Item("name")
        rs!Mobile = contact.Item("phoneNumber")
        rs!UserID = contact.Item("deviceId")
        rs!SID = contact.Item("_id")
        rs.Update
    Next

Else
    MsgBox "Unable to import data."
End If

End Sub
```